# Estimates about the number of lemmas in the Italian vocabulary

Tags: vocabulary

The number of lemmas in the vocabulary of Italian, intended as the the number of entries in a paper vocabulary, may change according to the vocabulary itself, that is, according to how much it is abridged.
This is of course true for every language.

I expect this number to grow with time because of new entrances, even though you could also argue that lemmas exit the vocabulary (because they're considered so obsolete nobody uses them any more).

Do you know what are the current estimates about the size of the Italian vocabulary?

Comment: @randomatlabuser Where do you find the 2 million? So, if you read the answer below, and assuming the reported number refers to unique lemmas, there's an order of magnitude more which should be covered by the different inflections.

Comment: see here: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lessico_dell%27italiano

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a more interesting question *would be*: what is an estimate of all admissible words in Italian (lemmas *and* inflections)? These are millions but, to my knowledge, nobody has ever made a reasonably exhaustive list, not even a reliable estimate - although, in my opinion, it would be relatively simple and cheap. [**EDIT**: Actually, according to [Lorenzetti 2004](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/varie/varie_026.html), cited by Con7e, Italian words are about 2 million!]

[Aspell dictionaries](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html) can be *expanded* so to obtain *many* inflections of the lemmas they contain: the list you get this way is not accurate, it's not complete, but it's certainly a useful starting point (note that the license is free, GNU Lesser General Public License). [Here](http://antonio-bonifati.blogspot.com.au/2009/10/lista-di-parole-italiane.html) you can find a code for Linux: according to the author of the blog, Aspell Italian dictionary lists about 1.9 million inflections.

The following code (from Linux terminal, once you have installed Aspell software and the Italian dictionary):

```
aspell -l it dump master | aspell -l it expand > italian.wordlist.all
```

generates `1,898,196` words but it might need a lot of cleaning up. Also note that the reported inflections miss the last vowel (so they do not cover gender, number, homographs, etc.).

Once you remove doubles, the number of unique entries falls to `1,135,672`. Check that out in Matlab:

```
fid = fopen('italian.wordlist.all');
C = textscan(fid, '%s');
fclose(fid);
C = C{1};
size(unique(C))
```

An interesting project is Marco Baroni's Morph-It project, [here](http://dev.sslmit.unibo.it/linguistics/morph-it.php): it «is a lexicon of inflected forms with their lemma and morphological features».

Just as an example of the extent to which a single Italian lemma can be *expanded*: if you *expand* the verb "giocare", i.e. if you conjugate it in all its possible forms, you get at least 362 inflections (including a handful of *homographs*). If you have doubts, look at the list below:

```
1   gioco
2   giochi
3   gioca
4   giochiamo
5   giochiam
6   giocate
7   giocano
8   giocan

9   giocavo
10  giocavi
11  giocava
12  giocavamo
13  giocavam
14  giocavate
15  giocavano
16  giocavan

17  giocai
18  giocasti
19  giocò
20  giocammo
21  giocaste
22  giocarono
23  giocaron

24  giocherò
25  giocherai
26  giocherà
27  giocheremo
28  giocherem
29  giocherete
30  giocheranno
31  giocheran


32  giochi
33  giochi
34  giochi
35  giochiamo
36  giochiam
37  giochiate
38  giochino
39  giochin

40  giocassi
41  giocassi
42  giocasse
43  giocassimo
44  giocassim
45  giocaste
46  giocassero
47  giocasser


48  giocherei
49  giocheresti
50  giocherebbe
51  giocheremmo
52  giochereste
53  giocherebbero
54  giocherebber


55  gioca
56  giochi
57  giochiamo
58  giochiam
59  giocate
60  giochino
61  giochin


62  giocando


63  giocante
64  giocanti

65  giocato
66  giocata
67  giocati
68  giocate


69  giocare
70  giocar
71  giocarsi


72  giocalo
73  giocala
74  giocali
75  giocale

76  giocami
77  giocati
78  giocagli
79  giocale
80  giocaci

81  giocamelo
82  giocamel
83  giocamela
84  giocameli
85  giocamele

86  giocatelo
87  giocatel
88  giocatela
89  giocateli
90  giocatele

91  giocaglielo
92  giocagliela
93  giocaglieli
94  giocagliele
95  giocagliel

96  giocacelo
97  giocacela
98  giocaceli
99  giocacele
100 giocacel

101 giocaci
102 giocamici
103 giocatici
104 giocaglici

105 giocane
106 giocamene
107 giocatene
108 giocagliene
109 giocacene

110 giochiamolo
111 giochiamola
112 giochiamoli
113 giochiamole
114 giochiamol

115 giochiamogli
116 giochiamole
117 giochiamoci

118 giochiamocelo
119 giochiamocela
120 giochiamoceli
121 giochiamocele

122 giochiamoglielo
123 giochiamogliela
124 giochiamoglieli
125 giochiamogliele
126 giochiamogliel

127 giochiamoci
128 giochiamone
129 giochiamocene
130 giochiamogliene

131 giocatelo
132 giocatela
133 giocateli
134 giocatele
135 giocatel

136 giocatemi
137 giocategli
138 giocatele
139 giocateci
140 giocatevi

141 giocatemelo
142 giocatemela
143 giocatemeli
144 giocatemele
145 giocatemel

146 giocateglielo
147 giocategliela
148 giocateglieli
149 giocategliele
150 giocategliel

151 giocatecelo
152 giocatecela
153 giocateceli
154 giocatecele
155 giocatecel

156 giocatevelo
157 giocatevela
158 giocateveli
159 giocatevele
160 giocatevel

161 giocateci
162 giocatemici
163 giocateglici
164 giocatevici

165 giocatene
166 giocatemene
167 giocategliene
168 giocatecene
169 giocatevene


170 giocandolo
171 giocandola
172 giocandoli
173 giocandole
174 giocandol

175 giocandomi
176 giocandoti
177 giocandogli
178 giocandole
179 giocandosi
180 giocandoci
181 giocandovi

182 giocandomelo
183 giocandomela
184 giocandomeli
185 giocandomele
186 giocandomel

187 giocandotelo
188 giocandotela
189 giocandoteli
190 giocandotele
191 giocandotel

192 giocandoglielo
193 giocandogliela
194 giocandoglieli
195 giocandogliele
196 giocandogliel

197 giocandoselo
198 giocandosela
199 giocandoseli
200 giocandosele
201 giocandosel

202 giocandocelo
203 giocandocela
204 giocandoceli
205 giocandocele
206 giocandocel

207 giocandovelo
208 giocandovela
209 giocandoveli
210 giocandovele
211 giocandovel

212 giocandoci
213 giocandomici
214 giocandotici
215 giocandoglici
216 giocandosici
217 giocandocici
218 giocandovici

219 giocandovi
220 giocandomivi
221 giocandotivi
222 giocandoglivi
223 giocandosivi
224 giocandocivi
225 giocandovivi

226 giocandocisi
227 giocandovisi

228 giocandone
229 giocandomene
230 giocandotene
231 giocandogliene
232 giocandosene
233 giocandocene
234 giocandovene

235 giocandocene
236 giocandovene


237 giocatolo
238 giocatola
239 giocatoli
240 giocatole
241 giocatol

242 giocatomi
243 giocatami
244 giocatimi
245 giocatemi

246 giocatoti
247 giocatati
248 giocatiti
249 giocateti

250 giocatogli
251 giocatagli
252 giocatigli
253 giocategli

254 giocatole
255 giocatale
256 giocatile
257 giocatele

258 giocatosi
259 giocatasi
260 giocatisi
261 giocatesi

262 giocatoci
263 giocataci
264 giocatici
265 giocateci

266 giocatovi
267 giocatavi
268 giocativi
269 giocatevi

270 giocatomelo
271 giocatamela
272 giocatimeli
273 giocatemele

274 giocatotelo
275 giocatatela
276 giocatiteli
277 giocatetele

278 giocatoglielo
279 giocatagliela
280 giocatoglielo
281 giocatoglielo

282 giocatoselo
283 giocatasela
284 giocatiseli
285 giocatesele

286 giocatone
287 giocatane
288 giocatine
289 giocatene

290 giocatomene
291 giocatamene
292 giocatimene
293 giocatemene

294 giocatotene
295 giocatatene
296 giocatitene
297 giocatetene

298 giocatogliene
299 giocatagliene
300 giocatigliene
301 giocategliene

302 giocatosene
303 giocatasene
304 giocatisene
305 giocatesene

306 giocatocene
307 giocatacene
308 giocaticene
309 giocatecene

310 giocatovene
311 giocatavene
312 giocativene
313 giocatevene


314 giocarlo
315 giocarla
316 giocarli
317 giocarle

318 giocarmi
319 giocarti
320 giocargli
321 giocarle
322 giocarci
323 giocarvi

324 giocarmelo
325 giocarmela
326 giocarmeli
327 giocarmele
328 giocarmel

329 giocartelo
330 giocartela
331 giocarteli
332 giocartele
333 giocartel

334 giocarglielo
335 giocargliela
336 giocarglieli
337 giocargliele
338 giocargliel

339 giocarselo
340 giocarsela
341 giocarseli
342 giocarsele
343 giocarsel

344 giocarcelo
345 giocarcela
346 giocarceli
347 giocarcele
348 giocarcel

349 giocarvelo
350 giocarvela
351 giocarveli
352 giocarvele
353 giocarvel

354 giocarne
355 giocarci
356 giocarvi

357 giocarmene
358 giocartene
359 giocargliene
360 giocarsene
361 giocarcene
362 giocarvene
```

The list above was written by myself - probably it is not accurate (--> there might be inaccuracies) nor complete (--> there might be more cases). Feel free to correct/complete it if you wish. I think that `1:362` is a reasonable estimate of the ratio `lemma/inflections` for verbs in Italian. Once you get reasonable estimates of the ratio `lemma/inflections` for nouns, adjectives and all other parts of speech that have inflections (store the estimates in vector `a`), once you get reasonable estimates of the number of lemmas for each of those parts of speech (store the estimates in vector `b`), you have an estimate of the admissible inflections in Italian (just calculate the inner product of the two vectors `a·b`).

Comment: randomatlabuser, interesting!

Comment: Some years ago I downloaded all the texts from http://www.liberliber.it/ and tried to collate a list of Italian inflections - too much noise. I did the same for English words with texts from http://www.gutenberg.org - same, too much noise. It's certainly a starting point though. There are people who collect corpora in different languages like http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/download.html , but the problem is always noise, accuracy and completeness.

Comment: This, indeed, is not an answer.

Comment: @Agos Why not? There's both an estimate and the way to obtain it. Furthermore, there's a useful example of the different inflections contributing to the obtained number.

Comment: The estimate misses a good part of the results: it's not inflecting by number, gender. My comment was just acknowledging the same phrase from the answer.

Comment: @Agos I cannot agree: the answer acknowledged the limits of the estimates in the first place (specifically: accuracy and completeness). If the existing estimates are poor, does that imply the answer is poor? You see that your point doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 15):

Well, according to Treccani:

> [..] il patrimonio lessicale italiano dovrebbe essere compreso tra le 215.000 e le 270.000 unità lessicali (lessemi)

More info can be found here: [Treccani Website](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/varie/varie_026.html)